# How can I find occurrence of an Id in a Scala String

Tags: string, algorithm, scala, grouping

Hello guys i'm kinda new on scala and i'm having this problem:

On the following string:

```
The ID 5d27e5d082c272591e25b8d5 is the only valid Field, 
The ID 5d27e5d06a77457139395318 is the only valid Field,
The ID 5d27e5d0431e726aeb5ab84f is the only valid Field,
The ID 5d27e5d282c27256cc24b6a2 is the only valid Field,
The ID 5d27e5d282c27256cc24b6a2 is the only valid Field,
The ID 5d27e5d282c2727ad524c567 is the only valid Field,
The ID 5d27e5d2431e724af25a1bd6 is the only valid Field,
The ID 5d27e5d36a774507723a7ea2 is the only valid Field, 
The ID 5d27e5d36a774507723a7ea2 is the only valid Field, 
The ID 5d27e5d482c2727ad524c576 is the only valid Field, 
The ID 5d27e5d482c272591e25b8ee is the only valid Field, 
The ID 5d27e5d482c2727ad524c576 is the only valid Field, 
The ID 5d27e5d482c2727ad524c576 is the only valid Field
```

i have a group of Ids that passed a validation process.

How can i make a new String with the Ids Grouped like This:

```
The id 5d27e5d282c27256cc24b6a2 has 4 errors
The id 5d27e5d482c2727ad524c576 has 2 errors
....
```

Tried this but i think there is a better way to achieve this

```
val replaced = input.replaceAll("The ID","").replaceAll("is the only valid Field","").trim.split(",").map(_.trim).groupBy(l => l).map(t => (t._1, t._2.length))

var newMessage = ""
replaced.foreach(s => {
  newMessage += s"The ID ${s._1} the only valid field on ${s._2.toString} rows, "
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? I will give you some clues: [`split`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/StringOps.html#split(separator:Char):Array[String]) - [`groupBy`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#groupBy[K](f:A=%3EK):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Array[A]]) - [**Regex**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) - [`mkString`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#mkString(sep:String):String).

Comment: Added an update

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit similar to other responses, but with a safe pattern match:

```
  val LineRegEx = "The ID (.+) is the only valid Field,?".r

  val output = 
    input
      .split('\n')
      .collect {
        case LineRegEx(id) => id
      }
      .groupBy(identity)
      .map { case (id, rows) => 
        s"The ID $id the only valid field on ${rows.length} rows"
      }
      .mkString("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple solution:

```
  (for{
    line <- all // each element of the list
    _::_::id::_ = line.split(" ").toList // split the line so you have the 'words'
  } yield id) // return the ids
    .groupBy(identity) // group it
    .map { case (id, list) => s"The id $id has ${list.size} errors" } // return the new Strings
```

`_::_::id::_` matches a List. Each element is separated by `::`. The last `_` refers to the rest of the list. `_` is used because you don't need them.

In the console:

```
scala> val all = Seq(
     |   "The ID 5d27e5d082c272591e25b8d5 is the only valid Field",
...
     |   "The ID 5d27e5d482c2727ad524c576 is the only valid Field",
     | )
all: Seq[String] = List(The ID 5d27e5d082c272591e25b8d5 is the only valid Field, ... , The ID 5d27e5d482c2727ad524c576 is the only valid Field)

scala> for{
....
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List(The id 5d27e5d282c27256cc24b6a2 has 2 errors, The id 5d27e5d06a7745713..., The id 5d27e5d36a774507723a7ea2 has 2 errors)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a rough outline of one approach.

```scala
str.split("\n")
   .groupBy(s => "ID ([^ ]+)".r.findFirstMatchIn(s).fold("none")(_.group(1)))
   .map{case (k,v) => s"ID $k has ${v.length} hits"}
   .mkString("\n")
//res0: String =
//ID 5d27e5d282c27256cc24b6a2 has 2 hits
//ID 5d27e5d06a77457139395318 has 1 hits
//ID 5d27e5d482c2727ad524c576 has 3 hits
//ID 5d27e5d082c272591e25b8d5 has 1 hits
//ID 5d27e5d482c272591e25b8ee has 1 hits
//ID 5d27e5d0431e726aeb5ab84f has 1 hits
//ID 5d27e5d2431e724af25a1bd6 has 1 hits
//ID 5d27e5d282c2727ad524c567 has 1 hits
//ID 5d27e5d36a774507723a7ea2 has 2 hits
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one alternative that works only on Scala `2.13`, as it uses the new **String Interpolator Extractor**.
*(where `input` is a string containing your sample input)*.

```
def getId(line: String): String = line match {
  case s"${_}The ID ${id} is the only valid Field${_}"=> id
}

val lines = input.split("\n")

val idsGrouped = 
  lines
    .filter(line => line.trim.nonEmpty)
    .groupBy(getId)
    .map {
      case (id, group) => id -> group.size
    }

val newMessage = idsGrouped.map {
  case (id, count) => s"The id ${id} has ${count} errors"
}.mkString("\n")

println(newMessage)
```

> The id 5d27e5d282c27256cc24b6a2 has 2 errors
>   The id 5d27e5d06a77457139395318 has 1 errors
>   The id 5d27e5d482c2727ad524c576 has 3 errors
>   The id 5d27e5d082c272591e25b8d5 has 1 errors
>   The id 5d27e5d482c272591e25b8ee has 1 errors
>   The id 5d27e5d0431e726aeb5ab84f has 1 errors
>   The id 5d27e5d2431e724af25a1bd6 has 1 errors
>   The id 5d27e5d282c2727ad524c567 has 1 errors
>   The id 5d27e5d36a774507723a7ea2 has 2 errors

---

Note, if you try this in the REPL right now, you will get an exception. It is [know](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11564) and [fixed](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8150) bug.
But on compiled code it runs without problems.